# Computer does not turn off, stuck in weird hibernation

Tags: windows-7, power-management, hibernate

Ok, So this problem is starting to occur in a lot more computers than one in our network.
We have several Dell V131 that when going into sleep mode seems to

- Shut down all USB-ports
- Internal Keyboard + Trackpad

Causing the computer to be unable to wake up.

What bothers me more is that when the user press Shut Down, the computer does in fact shut down... but not fully, it's still "on", screen is turned off but the fan is going "full speed".

It's sort of hibernating but not in a good way...
All the users effected by this have to shut down their computer via the hardware button... not so nice :(

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: What have you checked, tried and/or researched? Have you contacted Dell?

Comment: Have you changed or tried changing the power options in the BIOS?

Comment: BIOS is latest update, Power Options has not been temepered with and is the same across all computers (and don't seem to be shady)